# Send 100+ messages transactionaly to Azure service Bus

Tags: c#, azure, transactionscope, servicebus, azureservicebus

How to send more than 100 brokered messages to Azure Service Bus within a Transaction?

I know that `TransactionScope` does the trick but is limited to 100 messages.
And I know that if I send the messages as a Batch operation, the total size of the message is limited which causes the batches to be splited in different batches and the transaction is not guaranteed. And I think that the issue with the 100 messages remains even with batch send.

Does anyone found a solution?

Comment: Can you provide more information on what the messages represent?  Sending many thousands of messages within a single transactions is a pretty narrow use-case.

Comment: @Mitch Azure service bus doesn't support sending more than 100 messages within transaction and returns an exception. It is specified in the documentation.

Comment: Yes, I understand.  What I don't understand is why you are trying to send more than 100 messages.  If you explain what is leading you to want to send more than 100 messages, we may be able to provide a different solution which does not require you to send so many messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since you can't transfer all the information you need using Service Bus, you'll have to transfer it some other way.

Store all the data relevant to the transactions in another location (Azure Storage?), then send *one* message containing the location of data file - the file that contains information about the 10,000 operations that are supposed to take place in one transaction.

Your service, inside its transaction, will read the data file and perform the operations.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put several "logical" messages in one brokered message.  When your subscriber receives the brokered message, it can process each logical message, one at a time.

Comment: 1 list containing several objects can fit in 1 brokered message.  Then try to evaluate how much objects you have to put in your brokered message to limit your scope with 100 brokered messages in 1 transaction.

Comment: the limit of 100 brokered messages remains even if i put 10 messages within the same brokered messages.. I don't kown how many messages I have to send, Can be more than 10,000 messages to send. And I'm not able to use your solution of a "logical message"

Answer (score 0):

When clients communicate with Service Bus queues over the TCP protocol, the maximum number of concurrent connections to a single Service Bus queue is limited to 100. This number is shared between senders and receivers. If this quota is reached, subsequent requests for additional connections will be rejected and an exception will be received by the calling code. **[This limit is not imposed on clients connecting to the queues using REST-based API.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh767287.aspx)**

[A client application can access a REST-style service by using the WebHttpRelayBinding or by directly sending HTTP requests to the service endpoint.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee725246.aspx)

[Service Bus is a multi-protocol service: you can send and receive messages to or from the service using REST or .NET managed API, mixing and matching clients using different protocols in a given scenario.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh780717.aspx)

If you require more than 10,000 queues in a single Service Bus service namespace, you can contact the Azure support team and request an increase. To scale beyond 10,000 queues with Service Bus, you can also create additional service namespaces using the Microsoft Azure Management Portal.

[Because they offer support for sessions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj159884.aspx), transactions and a pub/sub model, Service Bus queues are the preferred choice when it comes to more complex messaging scenarios. However, Azure queues are a great option for supporting architectures that require high speed and high volume throughput for basic decoupling of their different components.

[From a developer’s point of view](https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2013/10/20/windows-azure-storage-queues-vs-windows-azure-service-bus-queues/), the biggest differences between Service Bus queues and Azure queues are the use of different namespaces and the way duplicated or poisoned messages are dealt with. Service Bus queues also offer a more flexible security mechanism through the use of ACS. Advanced scenarios, such as advanced filtering, deferred messages and dead-letter queues, will be covered in future articles.

- [Auxiliary link to Setting up the Service Bus in Azure](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-relay/)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why do I need 10000 queues? I just want 10000 messages in a queue within a transaction with isolation level serializable [send all or none]. And I'm using a service bus queue.